# How to simplify my code with this statement

Tags: c#

Recently I complete a function code, which need to check if the list contains more than one element, if the list is only one element, return it.
If the list is null or contains more than one, return null,
I finish the code like this.

```
return list.count == 1 ? list.SingleOrDefault() : null
```

But my boss think this code can be simpified, like:
`return  list.SingleOrDefault()`
I want to know if the C# exists function like this. I spend a lot of time.
Maybe I need to spend money to call for chatgpt:(

```
return list.count == 1 ? list.SingleOrDefault() : null
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: `Maybe I need to spend money to call for chatgpt:(` - yeah, why ask humans for free on stackoverflow when you can do this...

Comment: return list.FirstOrDefault();  is the correct way.

Comment: @ToufiqAhmed - no it isn't because if the list has 2 items FirstOrDefault will return the first time, but OP seems to want to return null

Comment: @Toufiq Ahmed, `FirstOrDefault` will not return null when list has more than 1 elements.

Comment: what is the reason for this kind of logic give us some insight

Comment: if you only want 1 element or null then you should pass condition in the function which ever you use firstordefault or singleordefault, try it as FirstOrDefault(x=>x.id == id)
otherwise forcing your logic like this doesn't make sense

Comment: [SingleOrDefault<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>): Returns the **only** element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty;](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-8.0#:~:text=TSource%3E(IEnumerable%3CTSource%3E)-,Returns%20the%20only%20element%20of%20a%20sequence%2C%20or%20a%20default%20value%20if%20the%20sequence%20is%20empty%3B%20this%20method%20throws%20an%20exception%20if%20there%20is%20more%20than%20one%20element%20in%20the%20sequence.,-C%23). checking the count seems not to be needed?

Comment: Your method is about as simplified as it gets, but if you don't want to use `Count == 1`, you could do:`return list.Skip(1).Any() ? null : list.FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C# 11 you can use a [List pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/list-patterns):

```cs
return list is [var x] ? x : default;
```

This tests whether the list (or array)

1. is not null (implicitly) and
2. contains exactly one element and
3. if yes declares a variable `x` and
4. assigns `x` the value of this element by using a [var pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#var-pattern).

This is why pattern matching is so powerful. It does four things (five if you count indexing the list separately) with the simple pattern `[var x]`.

Alternatively, a switch expression can be used:

```cs
return list switch { [var x] => x, _ => default };
```

Note that [SingleOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault) throws an exception if there is more than one element. Your code is also missing the test for a `null` list (unless you meant an empty list by *"the list is null"*).

Test:

```cs
List<string> list = null;
WriteTest();
list = new List<string>();
WriteTest();
list.Add("hello");
WriteTest();
list.Add("world");
WriteTest();

void WriteTest()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"result = {(list is [var x] ? x : default)}");
}
```

prints:

```
result =
result =
result = hello
result =
```

Comment: Maybe go the extra step and replace `null` with `default` to make this code work with value types.

Comment: someone having fun with the answer :)

Comment: Coding should be fun 

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think your boss is right. Here's how `SingleOrDefault` works:

- If there's no elements in the list, it returns the default value (`null` for reference types, 0 for value types or `false` for `bool`);
- If there's one element, it is returned.
- **If there's more than one element, it throws an exception.**

So if you use just `return list.SingleOrDefault()`, you'll need to use `try`/`catch` (in case there's more than one element). Is it a simplification?!

Comment: I guess boss is confused with `OrDefault` and thought that instead of throwing an exception on a List which has a count > 1 it will return the default value instead of throwing, rather easy to disproof - https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZZCx2P

Comment: @SNBS, I agree. I would use `return list?.Count == 1 ? list[0] : null;` though. No point using  `SingleOrDefault` after already checking that list has exactly one element.

Answer (score 0):

You're boss is correct if for example you have a list of string and uses just do list.SingleOrDefault()  it will return the only element it contains or null.
If it has more than one element though it will throw an exception System.InvalidOperationException

If you want to know if it contains a specific element you can do list.Contains(myObject)

If you really want to use list.count == 1 I would rather not use list.SingeOrDefault at all but do the following instead.
return list.count == 1 ? list[0] : null;

I am not sure I answered your question, let me know if there was something else you wanted to know.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my boss hate the statement `list.count == 1`, Maybe he thinks `SingleOrDefault()` returns null if more than one element, or may be another function realize it

Answer (score -1):

my suggestion is :

```
return list?.count == 1 ? list[0] : null;
```

Because the SingleOrDefault function checks the condition you already checked. So the best way is not to use SingleOrDefault function.
it's better not to use try/catch, because throwing an error makes your code unsafe and since errors are a software interrupt, they can slow down your program.

I tested this function with the two proposed methods and I came to the conclusion that the function written with the traditional method is faster than the function written with C#11 in most cases.
It should be noted that in some cases the function test written with 11 (in some cases but not all cases) was faster
The source code related to the test is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var condition = 100000000;
        var parameter = new List<int>() { 10,120,66,6654,41,655 };

        var CSharpTime = PerformanceCheck(CSharp, condition, parameter);
        var CSharp11Time = PerformanceCheck(CSharp11, condition, parameter);
        Console.WriteLine($"The parameter has more than 1 element");
        Console.WriteLine($"CSharpTime:{CSharpTime}");
        Console.WriteLine($"CSharp11Time:{CSharp11Time}");

        parameter = new List<int>() { 10 };
        CSharpTime = PerformanceCheck(CSharp, condition, parameter);
        CSharp11Time = PerformanceCheck(CSharp11, condition, parameter);
        Console.WriteLine($"The parameter has one element");
        Console.WriteLine($"CSharpTime:{CSharpTime}");
        Console.WriteLine($"CSharp11Time:{CSharp11Time}");

        parameter.Clear();
        CSharpTime = PerformanceCheck(CSharp, condition, parameter);
        CSharp11Time = PerformanceCheck(CSharp11, condition, parameter);
        Console.WriteLine($"The parameter is empty");
        Console.WriteLine($"CSharpTime:{CSharpTime}");
        Console.WriteLine($"CSharp11Time:{CSharp11Time}");

        parameter = null;
        CSharpTime = PerformanceCheck(CSharp, condition, parameter);
        CSharp11Time = PerformanceCheck(CSharp11, condition, parameter);
        Console.WriteLine($"The parameter is null");
        Console.WriteLine($"CSharpTime:{CSharpTime}");
        Console.WriteLine($"CSharp11Time:{CSharp11Time}");

        Console.ReadKey();
}
static int CSharp11(List<int> Datas) => Datas is [var x] ? x : default;
static int CSharp(List<int> Datas) => Datas?.Count == 1 ? Datas[0] : default;
static long PerformanceCheck(Func<List<int>, int> Method, int Condition, List<int> Datas)
{
    var result = new Stopwatch();
    result.Start();
    for (var counter = 0; counter < Condition; counter++)
    {
        var value = Method(Datas);
    }
    result.Stop();
    return result.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

console result :

> The parameter has more than 1 element
>
> CSharpTime:474
>
> CSharp11Time:522
>
> The parameter has one element
>
> CSharpTime:670
>
> CSharp11Time:662
>
> The parameter is empty
>
> CSharpTime:442
>
> CSharp11Time:443
>
> The parameter is null
>
> CSharpTime:346
>
> CSharp11Time:375

another console result :

[image: console result]